# Bison+Flex segfault no backtrace

Tags: debugging, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I'm trying to debug code generated by Bison + Flex (what a joy!).  It segfaults so badly that there isn't even stack information available to `gdb`.  Is there any way to make this combination generate code that's more debuggable?

Note that I'm trying to compile a reentrant lexer and parser (which is in itself a huge pain).

Below is the program that tries to use the `yyparse`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int res;
    if (argc == 2) {
        yyscan_t yyscanner;
        res = yylex_init(&yyscanner);
        if (res != 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize scanner\n");
           return res;
        }
        FILE* h = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

        if (h == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open: %s\n", argv[1]);
            return errno;
        }
        yyset_in(h, yyscanner);
        fprintf(stderr, "Scanner set\n");
        res = yyparse(&yyscanner);
        fprintf(stderr, "Parsed\n");
        yylex_destroy(&yyscanner);
        return res;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments\n");
    }
    print_usage();
    return 1;
}
```

Trying to run this gives:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /.../program 
[Inferior 1 (process 3292) exited with code 01]
```

Note 2: I'm passing `-d` to `flex` and `-t` to `bison`.

---

After shuffling the code around I was able to get backtrace.  But... it appears that passing `-t` has zero effect as does `%debug` directive in `*.y` file.  The only way to get traces is to set `yydebug = 1` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clobbering the stack by passing the address of `yyscanner` instead of its value to `yyparse`. Once the stack has been overwritten in that fashion, even gdb will be unable to provide accurate backtraces.

The `-d` and `%debug` directives cause bison to emit the code necessary to perform debugging traces. (This makes the parser code somewhat larger and a tiny bit slower, so it is not enabled by default.) That is necessary for tracing to work, but you still have to request traces by setting `yydebug` to a non-zero value.

This is mentioned right at the beginning of the [Bison manual section on tracing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing): (emphasis added)

> 8.4.1 Enabling Traces
>
> There are several means to **enable compilation** of trace facilities

And slightly later on:

> Once you have compiled the program with trace facilities, the way to request a trace is to store a nonzero value in the variable yydebug. You can do this by making the C code do it (in main, perhaps), or you can alter the value with a C debugger.

Unless you are working in an extremely resource-constrained environment, I suggest you *always* use the `-t` option, as do the Bison authors:

> We suggest that you always enable the trace option so that debugging is always possible.

Comment: Do you really think that the quotes from manual mean anything? They are just a pile of nonsense which can be interpreted in whichever way you want.  For instance, I looked into generated code and found the place where it says `yydebug = 1`.  So, I thought: they must have set it to `1`, but probably overwrote it somewhere.  With the amount of useless macros in the generated code, it's impossible to trace what it actually does. Furthermore, the need for two separate debug flags, which both mean the same thing, but only work when used together... best idea I've seen so far.

Comment: Perhaps you should find a toolset more in accord with your predefined notions of software engineering. While the manual may well not be perfect (as well as the product), it is much easier to read the manual than reverse-engineer the code. I think you would also find it hard to learn C by reading GCC's source code, although it would undoubtedly be an interesting exercise.

Comment: I can't find `yydebug = 1` in any generated code (except, of course, code which explicitly includes that statement as part of a user-defined function). Which version of bison are you using?

Comment: "it is much easier to read the manual" -- are you sure we are talking about the same program? The Bison manual, or, rather a dozen of them all making different obscure claims and references are a nightmare. The very lines you quoted make no sense. They are a testimony to the fact that the defaults are garbage and configuration is a quagmire.  Does it mean that I should look for a different program? Well no. This program is in public domain and everyone is free to use it / have their opinion on it. (contd)

Comment: The reason for me to use this one was to make an example. I need to make an example for comparison between different approaches to parsing. Bison is so bad in this respect that it takes many days to do something that normally doesn't take more than few hours.