# yyg->yy_buffer_stack points to garbage after yylex_init

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc

After some hours of debugging, I found that yyg->yy_bufer_stack points into some memory that it's not supposed to, and it later leads to segmentation fault:

```
(gdb) print yyg->yy_buffer_stack ? yyg->yy_buffer_stack[yyg->yy_buffer_stack_top] : 0
Cannot access memory at address 0x2aaaaaab0c680
(gdb) print yyg->yy_buffer_stack
$8 = (YY_BUFFER_STATE *) 0x40000
```

When I try reading the code for generated lexer, it is full of obscure and very suspicious references like negative indexing, intentional initialization of variables to garbage and so on...  It's not at all obvious how this could've been set to this bizarre value.  Any guesses as to what might have caused it?  Below is my code where I'm calling to `yyparse`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int res;
    if (argc == 2) {
        yyscan_t yyscanner;

        yylex_init(&yyscanner);
        FILE* h = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

        if (h == NULL) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open: %s\n", argv[1]);
            return errno;
        }
        yyset_in(h, yyscanner);
        fprintf(stderr, "Scanner set\n");
        res = yyparse(&yyscanner);
        fprintf(stderr, "Parsed\n");
        yylex_destroy(&yyscanner);
        return res;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number of arguments\n");
    }
    print_usage();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bison+Flex segfault no backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852287/bisonflex-segfault-no-backtrace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `yyparse` with the *address of* `yyscanner` but you're supposed to call it with the value. The address of `yyscanner` is somewhere in the C stack, whereas the `yyscanner` argument is expected to point to a block of memory in which `yylex` stores its persistent state. That obviously isn't going to work.

Note the example from the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant-Example.html#Reentrant-Example)

```
int main ( int argc, char * argv[] )
    {
        yyscan_t scanner;

        yylex_init ( &scanner );
        yylex ( scanner );
        yylex_destroy ( scanner );
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Whoa, that was it. Any idea though how can I not use `yyscan_t`, and use the correct `yyguts_t` instead?  Who on Earth would think about this being a good idea... I see that `bison` puts definition of `yyguts_t` into `*.c` file (why, oh why...) instead of an `*.h` file.  Is there any way to make it put definitions into right places?

Comment: yyguts_t is internal. You are not expected to use it. Opaque internal structures are a very common pattern (the only way that C can implement "private members") so I think you will find that many people on earth think it's a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I've heard this before.  But this is really nonsense.  This just makes life hard for no good reason.  So... there wouldn't be any way to do this with `flex` / `bison` only? One would need to parse their output and re-generate it? :D

Comment: There is no need to use the internal structures, and if you do so your code will eventually break when the definitions of those structures are changed. There is a complete set of access functions which are not particularly difficult to use. If you encounter problems using them, feel free to ask a specific question.

Comment: Because the definitions of "access functions" are scattered around thousands of lines of garbage code... it should be easier to use them than just have access to the actual thing you need to work with? These "access functions" are undocumented, have no interface defined, they can only be "discovered" (not really) when you already know they are there. This is one of the worst interfaces for the real-world program I've seen in about 20 years I've been programming, and I've seen a lot of garbage, like the `HANDLE` "opaque type" created by overmind from Richmond etc.

Comment: The yyscan_t getter and setter functions are documented here: http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Reentrant-Functions.html